# show files and directories in php

Tags: php

Hi I want to show to table my files and directories. And when it is files I want to show date of last update and size. Whats wrong with my code please?

```
<?
$whole_path = ("../directory/");

$dirFiles = array();
if ($handle = opendir($whole_path)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." &&  $file != ".." && $file != "index.php" && $file != "Thumbnails") {
            $dirFiles[] = $file;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
sort($dirFiles);
foreach($dirFiles as $file => $value)
    {
    $name = basename($value);
    if(is_file($value))
          {
          $mod_date=date("d/m/Y H:i", filemtime($value));
          $size = filesize($value);
          }
?>

            <tr>
              <td><? echo $name; ?></td>
              <td><? echo $mod_date; ?></td>
              <td><? echo $size; ?></td>
            </tr>
<?}?>
```

Comment: Well, you have to tell what is wrong. What did you expect? What happens instead? Are you aware of uninitialized variables and variable re-use within loops? If not, raising error-reporting to the highest level might be beneficial for your development purposes.

Comment: i expect that it shows me name, last update and size of files and directories. I get only names of files and directories

Comment: I am a beginner, can you recommend me some advice?

Comment: Then start with outputting `$value` as well before the `$name`, so you can see which file-path was actually used. It might just not be correct. If not correct, then `is_file()` does always return `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding `$whole_path` to the filename, so `is_file()` is looking in the wrong place.  `$value = $whole_path . $value;`